# What is a simple outlier detection algorithm for contextual data?

Tags: database, algorithm, machine-learning, outliers

I am looking for a simple outlier detection technique that helps me to get rid of outliers in my data set.
I have 2 million samples that are Partial Discharge measurements obtained from 3000 sinusoidal cycles. That means the measurement equipment are capable of measuring necessary data even in small degree variations in a cycle.
so my data are measurements from applying a sinusoidal wave to an insulation over time and recording them to get 2 million samples.
the question here is that data have a context and I can't detect outliers using conventional methods and algorithms like kNN search, because important data would be removed from data set since they have large distance from other data.
I have searched and I discovered that there are different methods for outlier detection in contextual data set. Would you help me?

Answer (score 0):

1 option is to perform  feature engineering and converting your contextual data to numeric data, for example "1 hot encoding" , our getting counts, for example train with a feature of "5 daily occurrences on average" and then perform your prediction on a daily basis.